# Best approach to emulating 6502 clock cycles?

Tags: assembly, emulation, 6502

I've been working on the CPU for an NES emulator, and I was wondering about what is the best way to manage cycles for multi-cycle instructions. 
(Assuming the time delay of a cycle is implemented) I could increment the cycles individually per each step of the instruction, like so:

```
void EXAMPLE_INSTRUCTION(){
step1();
cycles++;

step2();
cycles++;

step3();
cycles++;
}
```

Or take the 3 cycles all at once when the instruction finishes, like this:

```
void EXAMPLE_INSTRUCTION(){
step1();
step2();
step3();

cycles+=3;
```

Trying to track down which parts of an instruction take a cycle and counting on my hands is getting annoying, and I was wondering if there are any downsides to removing my current implementation of clock cycles in favor of just taking all of the cycles at once before the instruction finishes.

Comment: You might be approaching it backwards. I would think you'd want a timer that can tell your emulator how many clock cycles to emulate, and then count backward and return the state once it hits zero, or if it WOULD hit zero before completing an instruction.

Comment: How are those two approaches materially different?  If the system cannot tell/see the difference, then it doesn't matter.  If it makes a difference to something then you'll need to make a choice based on that.  But there's nothing you're showing that suggests the choice matters.

Comment: @GarrGodfrey I do have my code set up to decrement clock cycles, I just though using ++ would be simpler for the sake of the example

Comment: As @ErikEidt said, it makes no difference unless something else is looking at the clock cycles. For instance, a useful concept in emulators is to have an event queue (interrupts or other activity elsewhere in the emulated machine) each one scheduled N1, N2, etc clock cycles in the future. Then instead of directly modifying the cycles you call the queue to subtract a number of cycles, potentially triggering those events. You could call with 1 for each "step" inside an instruction, or call with the total cycles at the end of the instruction if cycle-level accuracy isn't required.

Comment: @NickWestgate: A sorted queue of when each pending "async" event (like interrupts) will happen makes a lot of sense.  If an instruction can't complete before the next interrupt, you could skip simulating any of its steps, if that's how the real CPU works (interrupt aborts and doesn't commit any partial progress).  If a load can initiate a memory bus cycle but then get interrupted before actually completing, that extra contention for the bus might matter for DMA throughput...

Comment: @PeterCordes Yes, exactly. You can add a lot of emulated concurrency - often without actually needing threads or concurrency primitives. I first had this idea back in the 90s (hand-rolled in ARM assembly ; - ) but it's pretty common now.

Comment: @PeterCordes The 6502 only checks the status of interrupts at the end of each instruction.

Comment: @JeremyP: Ok that makes sense.  As I was writing that comment, I was wondering how a microcoded CPU would manage to roll back any of the progress it made if it wanted to bail out in the middle of an instruction.  Just finishing the instruction before handling an interrupt makes more sense.

Comment: @PeterCordes the 6502 is a ridiculously simple processor. Pretty much always it took the unsophisticated approach. Another example: the clock was divided into two and the second half of each clock cycle was always a memory access *even if the CPU didn't need to access memory* at that time. This made the memory cycle logic really straight forward.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is that it depends.

---

If your emulator is not cycle accurate, you can add all the cycles on at once at the end. In fact, you can have a lookup table of the cycle count for each instruction so you don't have to add increment `cycles` in every single  instruction implementation.

There is a caveat to that approach which is that you need to be aware that not all instructions have constant cycle counts. For example all the branch instructions take:

- 2 cycles
- +1 if the branch is taken
- +1 if the branch is taken and the offset crosses a page boundary (because you have to change the high byte of the program counter).

So `BNE` could take 2, 3 or 4 cycles. The approach I took was to keep the base count in a lookup table and add extra cycles in the instruction implementations as required.

---

If you want a cycle accurate emulation, you will have to use your first approach because accesses to the data bus should probably occur with an accurate cycle count.

For example, reading and/or writing to IO registers can trigger external events. Normally you'd expect the read or write to be the last thing that happens during instruction execution but you might want to accurately simulate weird things like incrementing a memory location that happens to be an IO register or accidentally jumping to a location that is an IO register.

Comment: I was planning to basically take the cycles at whatever the "final step" of the instruction is, so at the end of a branch or something I can just put in the appropriate amount of cycles for each case directly in the if() else() with the rest of the instruction code. Thanks!